# Zend framework plugins issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

Here is the content of file User.php

```
<?php 
class My_Controller_Plugin_User extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        echo 'preDispatch is called';
    }
}
```

Which is located in library/My/Controller/Plugin/ folder.

In bootstrap.php I'm trying to register the plugin with this

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $front->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_User);
```

but I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'My_Controller_Plugin_User' not found
```

as error. What I miss here ?

Comment: How are you setting up the autoloader and/or registering your 'My' namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also put new namespaces to config.ini

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Foo_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Bar_"
```

ZF will load it automatically.